# On the $f$-stable subspace of a vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Recall that a subspace $U$ of $V$ is called $f$-stable if $f(U)\subset U.$ Here $f\in End(V).$

Suppose that the set $\{x, y\}$ is a basis for the vector space $V.$ Let $f\in End(V)$ such that $f(x) = 0, f(y) = x.$ Prove that $U = \mbox{Span}\{x\}$ is one-dimensional $f$-stable subspace of $V.$ Moreover,  it is unique.

How to prove that  it is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $W=span (z)$ be a one dimensional subspace with $f(W) \subset W$. We can write $z=ax+by$ for some $a$ and $b$. Now $f(z)=cz$ for some $c$. So $af(x)+bf(y)=cz=c(ax+by)$ or $bx=c(ax+by)$. By independence of $x$ and $y$ we get $b=ca$ and $cb=0$. Can you finish?

Comment: Why $bx = c(ax + by)$? How to prove $W = U$?

Comment: @Success I just used the facts that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=x$ to get $bx =c(ax+by)$. To show that $W=U$ what you have to show is that $z$ is scalar multiple of $x$ (so that  $x$ and $z$ span the same one dimensional space). To show that $z$ is scalar multiple of $x$  show that $b=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!